# Rails Nested Attributes properly assigning parent_id as index, but isn't assigning additional attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nested-attributes, has-many, rails-console

I've been working on implementing a new model that belongs to one of our web apps existing models. Eventually, I want to build out a nested form. I understand that the form, and strong params can have it's own suite of issues, but I am currently struggling to get the models to behave as I would expect in the rails console.

Rails 4.2.7, Postgres DB

UPDATE - 10/3/16 - Still trying to find the right solution, but have made some changes

Our work is with Schools and Districts, and this particular case deals with surveys and how a survey is assigned to a school and district. Until now, a survey has been assigned to a district with a SurveyAssignment model, and some down the line logic assumed that all schools in a district were also "assigned" to the survey. Now, we want to be able to add more granularity to the SurveyAssignment and allow some specificity at the school level.

So I created a SchoolSurveyAssignment model and started to get the bits in place.

Here is the relevant model info:

```
class District < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :schools, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :survey_assignments, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end

class School
  ...
  belongs_to :district
  has_many :school_survey_assignments
  has_many :survey_assignments, :through => :school_survey_assignments

  ...
end

class SurveyAssignment
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :survey
  has_one :survey_version, through: :survey
  has_many :school_survey_assignments, inverse_of: survey_assignment
  has_many :schools, :through => :school_survey_assignments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_survey_assignments

  attr_accessor :survey_group, :survey_version_type, :survey_version_id, :school_survey_assignments_attributes
  validates :survey_id, presence: true
end 

class SchoolSurveyAssignment
  belongs_to :survey_assignment, inverse_of: :school_survey_assignments
  belongs_to :school

  attr_accessor :school_id, :survey_assignment_id, :grades_affected, :ulc_affected
  validates_presence_of :survey_assignment
  validates :school_id, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :survey_assignment_id}
end
```

Relevant Controller code:

```
class SurveyAssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_district
  before_action :set_survey_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def new
    @new_survey_assignment = SurveyAssignment.new()
    @district.schools.each do |school|
      @new_survey_assignment.school_survey_assignments.build(school_id: school.id)
    end
  end

  def create
    @survey_assignment = SurveyAssignment.new(survey_assignment_params)
    if @survey_assignment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Survey successfully assigned to #{@district.name}"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was a problem assigning this survey to #{@district.name}"
    end
    redirect_to district_survey_assignments_path(@district)
  end

  def survey_assignment_params
    params.require(:survey_assignment).permit(:survey_id, :status, :survey_version_id, school_survey_assignments_attributes: [:id, :survey_assignment_id, :school_id, grades_affected: [], ulc_affected: []]).tap do |p|
      p[:district_id] = @district.id
      p[:school_year] = session[:selected_year]
    end
  end

  def set_district
    @district = District.find(params[:district_id])
  end
```

Here is the relevant schema info:

```
create_table "school_survey_assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "survey_assignment_id"
  t.integer "school_id"
  t.integer "grades_affected",      default: [], array: true
  t.string  "ulc_affected",         default: [], array: true
 end

add_index "school_survey_assignments", ["school_id"], name: "index_school_survey_assignments_on_school_id", using: :btree
add_index "school_survey_assignments", ["survey_assignment_id"], name: "index_school_survey_assignments_on_survey_assignment_id", using: :btree

create_table "survey_assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "district_id"
  t.integer  "survey_id"
  t.integer  "status"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "school_year"
  t.integer  "last_response_status_id"
end

add_index "survey_assignments", ["district_id"], name: "index_survey_assignments_on_district_id", using: :btree
```

Once these were in place, I stepped into my rails console and attempted the following:

```
2.3.1 :002 > sa1 = SurveyAssignment.create(district_id: 3, survey_id: 508, school_year: 2017)
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "survey_assignments" ("district_id", "survey_id", "school_year", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["district_id", 3], ["survey_id", 508], ["school_year", 2017], ["created_at", "2016-09-30 21:30:20.205144"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-30 21:30:20.205144"]]
  (7.2ms)  COMMIT
=> #<SurveyAssignment id: 369, district_id: 3, survey_id: 508, status: nil, created_at: "2016-09-30 21:30:20", updated_at: "2016-09-30 21:30:20", school_year: 2017, last_response_status_id: nil>
2.3.1 :003 > sa2 = SurveyAssignment.create(district_id: 3, survey_id: 508, school_year: 2017)
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "survey_assignments" ("district_id", "survey_id", "school_year", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["district_id", 3], ["survey_id", 508], ["school_year", 2017], ["created_at", "2016-09-30 21:30:30.701197"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-30 21:30:30.701197"]]
  (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<SurveyAssignment id: 370, district_id: 3, survey_id: 508, status: nil, created_at: "2016-09-30 21:30:30", updated_at: "2016-09-30 21:30:30", school_year: 2017, last_response_status_id: nil>
```

So now, I've successfully created two Survey Assignments. I'm now going to create two School Survey Assignments off of sa1:

```
2.3.1 :004 > [{school_id: 5}, {school_id: 6}].each do |ssa|
2.3.1 :005 >     sa1.school_survey_assignments.create(ssa)
2.3.1 :006?>   end
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 SchoolSurveyAssignment Exists (2.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "school_survey_assignments" WHERE ("school_survey_assignments"."school_id" = 5 AND "school_survey_assignments"."survey_assignment_id" = 369) LIMIT 1
 SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "school_survey_assignments" ("survey_assignment_id") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["survey_assignment_id", 369]]
  (6.4ms)  COMMIT
  (0.6ms)  BEGIN
 SchoolSurveyAssignment Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "school_survey_assignments" WHERE ("school_survey_assignments"."school_id" = 6 AND "school_survey_assignments"."survey_assignment_id" = 369) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "school_survey_assignments" ("survey_assignment_id") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["survey_assignment_id", 369]]
  (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> [{:school_id=>5}, {:school_id=>6}]
2.3.1 :007 > sa1.save
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Now, it looks like I've successfully created two SchoolSurveyAssignments with survey_assignment_id = 369 and school_ids = 5 and 6

```
2.3.1 :008 > sa1.school_survey_assignments
  SchoolSurveyAssignment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "school_survey_assignments".* FROM "school_survey_assignments" WHERE "school_survey_assignments"."survey_assignment_id" = $1  [["survey_assignment_id", 369]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<SchoolSurveyAssignment id: 5, survey_assignment_id: 369, school_id: nil, grades_affected: [], ulc_affected: []>, #<SchoolSurveyAssignment id: 6, survey_assignment_id: 369, school_id: nil, grades_affected: [], ulc_affected: []>]>
```

As you can see from the ActivRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy, both of the SchoolSurveyAssignments were created, with survey_assignment_id: 369, but with a nil school_id. This is troubling as it seems to be

1. Ignoring the parameters being passed into the create function, and
2. ignoring the validation of school_id

Another item that I don't understand is the following:

```
2.3.1 :009 > SchoolSurveyAssignment.find(5).survey_assignment_id
  SchoolSurveyAssignment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "school_survey_assignments".* FROM "school_survey_assignments" WHERE "school_survey_assignments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
=> nil
2.3.1 :011 > SchoolSurveyAssignment.find(5).survey_assignment.id
  SchoolSurveyAssignment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "school_survey_assignments".* FROM "school_survey_assignments" WHERE "school_survey_assignments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  SurveyAssignment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "survey_assignments".* FROM "survey_assignments" WHERE "survey_assignments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 369]]
 => 369
```

Calling .survey_assignment_id should return the attribute on the SchoolSurveyAssignment and give 369. .survey_assignment.id is simply just grabbing the parent object's ID. I would expect both to return the same value, but one returns nil.

The end use case is making a SurveyAssignment form that lets the user set the attributes for a new SurveyAssignment and also set the attributes for X number of SchoolSurveyAssignments (based on # of schools in a district; varies from 2 to 15). Once I get a better grasp on how these models are interacting, I feel confident in executing this goal, but the behavior I'm seeing doesn't make sense to me, and I was hoping to find some clarity on implementing these related models.  I feel like I'm bouncing around the answer, but am missing a key detail.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: can you post controller code?  I assume you are using strong parameters?

Comment: I am using strong params. I will update with Controller code. This may expose my ignorance, but I was under the impression that controller methods only get hit with true HTTP requests/routing, and that running commands from the console wouldn't hit those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your `attr_accessor` lines of code.  `attr_accessor` shouldn't be used for attributes that are persisted in the database and it's probably messing up the methods that ActiveRecord already provides by default, causing those attributes to not be saved properly

```
class SurveyAssignment
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :survey
  has_one :survey_version, through: :survey
  has_many :school_survey_assignments, inverse_of: survey_assignment
  has_many :schools, :through => :school_survey_assignments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_survey_assignments

  validates :survey_id, presence: true
end 

class SchoolSurveyAssignment
  belongs_to :survey_assignment, inverse_of: :school_survey_assignments
  belongs_to :school

  validates_presence_of :survey_assignment
  validates :school_id, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :survey_assignment_id}
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I attempted the create per your suggestion and it creates the SurveyAssignment but not the school_survey_assignments.

I've also tried what the api.rubyonrails.org docs say for the one-to-many example
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model

That also resulted in creating the Survey Assignment, but not creating the SchoolSurveyAssignments.

Comment: Based on some advice from a coworker, I've moved towards using a custom Form object class to handle the creation of the Survey Assignment and the SchoolSurveyAssignments. 

It's appropriately handling the params, and I know I am getting all the requisite params through the SurveyAssignmentController and into this object.

However, it is still not saving the attributes on the child model (school_survey_assignment). It would appear I have some sort of other issue, rather than any issue with nested forms/form objects

Comment: made an edit to original post.  try commenting out/deleting the `attr_accessor` lines

Comment: Yup, that was it. I deleted the attr_accessor lines in my SchoolSurveyAssignment model and now my form object works perfectly. I suppose I could go back and get the nested_attributes approach to work, but this form object seems elegant enough.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, School and SurveyAssignment don't know each other, school_id becomes nil. In your app, these models have m-to-n association indirectly, so how about using  has_many through association between models?

In School model, add below:

```
has_many :survey_assignments, :through => :school_survey_assignments
```

In SurveyAssignments model, add below:

```
has_many :schools, :through => :school_survey_assignments
```

For the last question, both codes seem to be same..

Comment: thanks for pointing out the needed association. I added that, and I'm still running into some issues. I've updated the code to reflect the changes.

With respect to the last question, the difference is in .id vs _id

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that, but both .id and _id works in my PC. Is your issue  still .id vs _id?　BTW, in SurveyAssignment class,  inverse_of:  survey_assignment  is missing ':'  before 'survey_assignment', I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. That missing : was a typo in going from my editor to Stackoverflow, but good catch.